# Parts of the same app work but together don't work

Tags: android, localization, android-wifi, rssi, indoor-positioning-system

My app is formed by 2 parts: one for localization INDOOR and one for localization OUTDOOR.
Separately, these parts work... But when I combine them in one big app, the OUTDOOR part doesn't work anymore!
I don't know why...
Can you help me?
I write the code:

MAIN

```
package martina_cennamo.localization;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//CERCO GLI ELEMENTI BUTTON E BUTTON2

        Button OutDoor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button InDoor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

//CLICCANDO SU BUTTON FACCIO APRIRE UNA NUOVA ACTIVITY

        OutDoor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //DEFINISCO L'INTENZIONE DI APRIRE UNA NUOVA ACTIVITY
                Intent openActivityO=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityO.class);
                //APRO L'ACTIVITY ACTIVITYO.JAVA
                startActivity(openActivityO);

            }
        });

//CLICCANDO SU BUTTON2 FACCIO APRIRE UNA NUOVA ACTIVITY

        InDoor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent openActivityI=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityI.class);
                startActivity(openActivityI);

            }


        });
    }

    //ALTRI OVERRIDE
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

ACTIVITYO (OUTDOOR)

```
package martina_cennamo.localization;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;



public class ActivityO extends AppCompatActivity {

    public WifiManager wifi;
    private String rete;

    private String ssid1;
    private String ssid2;
    private String ssid3;

    private int level1;
    private int level2;
    private int level3;

    private String BSSID1;
    private String BSSID2;
    private String BSSID3;

    private Document htmlDocument;
    private TextView parsedHtmlNode;
    private String html;

    private TextView text;
    private TextView text2;
    private TextView text3;
    private TextView retevicina;

    Button indietro;

    List<ScanResult> results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_o);

        parsedHtmlNode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.html_content);

        JsoupAsyncTask jsoupAsyncTask = new JsoupAsyncTask();
        jsoupAsyncTask.execute();

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        indietro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.indietro);

        retevicina = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);



        //TORNA ALLA HOME
        indietro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home);

        indietro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent back=new Intent(ActivityO.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(back);
            }


        });
        //FINE
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class JsoupAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);


            wifi.startScan();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3333);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            results = wifi.getScanResults();


            ScanResult result1 = results.get(0);
            ssid1 = result1.SSID;

            ScanResult result2 = results.get(1);
            ssid2 = result2.SSID;

            ScanResult result3 = results.get(2);
            ssid3 = result3.SSID;

            level1 = results.get(0).level;
            level2 = results.get(1).level;
            level3 = results.get(2).level;

            BSSID1 = results.get(0).BSSID;
            BSSID2 = results.get(1).BSSID;
            BSSID3 = results.get(2).BSSID;

//COME PRENDO LA RETE CON LA POTENZA MAGGIORE?

            if (level1 >= level2 && level1 >= level3) {

                rete = ssid1;

            } else {
                if (level2 >= level1 && level2 >= level3) {
                    rete = ssid2;

                } else {
                    if (level3 >= level1 && level3 >= level2) {
                        rete = ssid3;
                    }
                }
            }
//mostrare in una textview latitudine e longitudine
            try {

                htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect("http://geomena.org/essid/" + rete).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22")
                        .timeout(30000).get();

//selezionare da html di ESSID/Vodafone - PROVA

                for (Element body : htmlDocument.select("body")) {
                    for (Element div : body.select("div[id*=content]")) {
                        for (Element table : div.select("table")) {
                            for (Element tbody : table.select("tbody")) {
                                for (Element tr : tbody.select("tr:eq(0)")) {
                                    Elements td = tr.select("td");
                                    html = td.get(3).text();

                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            text.setText("SSID: " + ssid1 + "   RSSI: " + level1 + "MAC: " + BSSID1);
            text2.setText("SSID: " + ssid2 + "   RSSI: " + level2 + "MAC: " + BSSID2);
            text3.setText("SSID: " + ssid3 + "   RSSI: " + level3 + "MAC: " + BSSID3);

            parsedHtmlNode.setText(html);

            retevicina.setText("La rete più vicina è " + rete);
        }
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY I (INDOOR_1)

```
package martina_cennamo.localization;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityI extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button localizza;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_i);

        localizza=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);


        localizza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent Wifi=new Intent(ActivityI.this,ActivityWifi.class);
                startActivity(Wifi);

            }


        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_i, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY WIFI (INDOOR_2)

```
package martina_cennamo.localization;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class ActivityWifi extends AppCompatActivity {

    public WifiManager wifi;

    ImageView cucina;
    ImageView soggiorno;
    ImageView letto_1;
    ImageView letto_2;
    ImageView letto_3;

    TextView posizione;

    Button locate;

    final Fingerprint f1= new Fingerprint();
    final Fingerprint f2= new Fingerprint();
    final Fingerprint f3= new Fingerprint();
    final Fingerprint f4= new Fingerprint();
    final Fingerprint f5= new Fingerprint();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi);

        f1.setStanza("Cucina");
        f2.setStanza("Soggiorno");
        f3.setStanza("Letto_1");
        f4.setStanza("Letto_2");
        f5.setStanza("Letto_3");

        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {

            f1.rete[i] = new Rete();
            f2.rete[i] = new Rete();
            f3.rete[i] = new Rete();
            f4.rete[i] = new Rete();
            f5.rete[i] = new Rete();
        }
//IMPOSTO I VALORI DEI 3 WIFI PER OGNI STANZA
        f1.rete[0].set_SSID("Vodafone-27661039");
        f1.rete[0].set_RSSI(-85);
        f1.rete[1].set_SSID("NokiaWifi");
        f1.rete[1].set_RSSI(-53);
        f1.rete[2].set_SSID("extender");
        f1.rete[2].set_RSSI(-69);


        f2.rete[0].set_SSID("Vodafone-27661039");
        f2.rete[0].set_RSSI(-75);
        f2.rete[1].set_SSID("NokiaWifi");
        f2.rete[1].set_RSSI(-67);
        f2.rete[2].set_SSID("extender");
        f2.rete[2].set_RSSI(-44);


        f3.rete[0].set_SSID("Vodafone-27661039");
        f3.rete[0].set_RSSI(-59);
        f3.rete[1].set_SSID("NokiaWifi");
        f3.rete[1].set_RSSI(-79);
        f3.rete[2].set_SSID("extender");
        f3.rete[2].set_RSSI(-58);


        f4.rete[0].set_SSID("Vodafone-27661039");
        f4.rete[0].set_RSSI(-36);
        f4.rete[1].set_SSID("NokiaWifi");
        f4.rete[1].set_RSSI(-84);
        f4.rete[2].set_SSID("extender");
        f4.rete[2].set_RSSI(-70);

        f5.rete[0].set_SSID("Vodafone-27661039");
        f5.rete[0].set_RSSI(-57);
        f5.rete[1].set_SSID("NokiaWifi");
        f5.rete[1].set_RSSI(-84);
        f5.rete[2].set_SSID("extender");
        f5.rete[2].set_RSSI(-42);

        //EFFETTUO LA SCANSIONE DEI WIFI
        wifi=(WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){

            wifi.startScan();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3333);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();

        if(results.size()<3){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hai trovato solo " + results.size() +"reti! Scansiona di nuovo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        //FINE SCANSIONE
        //TORNA ALLA LOCATE
        locate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.locate);

        locate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent openlocate = new Intent(ActivityWifi.this, ActivityI.class);
                startActivity(openlocate);
            }


        });
        //FINE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        cucina=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cucina);
        soggiorno=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.soggiorno);
        letto_1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.letto_1);
        letto_2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.letto_2);
        letto_3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.letto_3);
        posizione=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.posizione);



        List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();

        final Rete[] retiscansione = new Rete[results.size()];

        for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
            ScanResult sr=results.get(i);
            retiscansione[i]=new Rete();
            retiscansione[i].set_SSID(sr.SSID);
            retiscansione[i].set_RSSI(sr.level);
        }

        final int distanza1=f1.distanza(retiscansione);
        final int distanza2=f2.distanza(retiscansione);
        final int distanza3=f3.distanza(retiscansione);
        final int distanza4=f4.distanza(retiscansione);
        final int distanza5=f5.distanza(retiscansione);

        double distanzamin = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(distanza1, distanza2), Math.min(distanza3, distanza4)),distanza5);

        if(distanzamin==distanza1){
            soggiorno.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            posizione.setText("Sei nella stanza: "+f1.getStanza());
        }
        if(distanzamin==distanza2){
            cucina.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            posizione.setText("Sei nella stanza: "+f2.getStanza());
        }
        if(distanzamin==distanza3){
            cucina.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            soggiorno.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            posizione.setText("Sei nella stanza: "+f3.getStanza());
        }
        if(distanzamin==distanza4){
            cucina.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            soggiorno.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            posizione.setText("Sei nella stanza: "+f4.getStanza());
        }
        if(distanzamin==distanza5){
            cucina.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            soggiorno.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            letto_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            posizione.setText("Sei nella stanza: "+f5.getStanza());
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_wifi, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

FINGERPRINT CLASS

```
package martina_cennamo.localization;

/**
 * Created by pc1 on 01/11/2015.
 */
public class Fingerprint
{

    String stanza;
    Rete[] rete = new Rete[3];
    public int a=0;
    public int b=0;
    public int c=0;


    public void setStanza(String stanza)
    {
        this.stanza = stanza;
    }

    public String getStanza()
    {
        return stanza;
    }

    public int distanza(Rete[] trovate){


        int distanzacalcolata=0;


        for(int i=0;i<trovate.length ;i++)
        {
            if (trovate[i].get_SSID().equals("Vodafone-27661039"))
            {a=trovate[i].get_RSSI();}
            if (trovate[i].get_SSID().equals("NokiaWifi"))
            {b=trovate[i].get_RSSI();}
            if (trovate[i].get_SSID().equals("extender"))
            {c=trovate[i].get_RSSI();}
        }

        distanzacalcolata=(int)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rete[0].get_RSSI()-a,2)+Math.pow(rete[1].get_RSSI()-b,2)+Math.pow(rete[2].get_RSSI()-c,2));

        return distanzacalcolata;
    }



}
```

RETE CLASS

```
package martina_cennamo.localization;

/**
 * Created by pc1 on 01/11/2015.
 */

public class Rete {

    String SSID;
    int RSSI;

    public String get_SSID()
    {
        return this.SSID;
    }

    public int get_RSSI()
    {
        return this.RSSI;
    }

    public void set_SSID(String SSID)
    {
        this.SSID=SSID;
    }

    public void set_RSSI(int RSSI)
    {
        this.RSSI=RSSI;
    }



}
```

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: When I click on the button "outdoor" (because I want to open the ActivityO) the app crashs!

Answer (score 0):

I put together your code and found two issues that came up on the Outdoor activity.

The first issue was a null pointer error with the indietro button.  You first initialize it to a button named R.id.indietro, then you switch to R.id.home.

```
    indietro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.indietro);
    ...
    //TORNA ALLA HOME
    indietro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home);
```

Take out that second initializer and it will work, or make sure that the button name matches the button you want to control.

The second issue came after I fixed the button.  It was a simple permission issue.  Make sure that the INTERNET permission is listed in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After those things were done, the app did not crash.